# Specifying app_id and app_name for facebookConnect in a multi-device hybrid app in VS2013 & W8.1

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2013, cordova-plugins, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I've been banging my head on this one for a while now.

How do I specify the app_id and app_name when trying to use the facebookConnect plugin in a Multi-Device Hybrid app in Visual Studio 2013?

If I create a new solution using the CLI approach; something similar to:

```
cordova create MyTest <blah> <blah> <blah>
```

I can probably use the CLI to add the plugin with a command similar to: (Untested and the command might be slightly wrong)

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect
```

BUT...

How do I add it when I've created a Mutli-Device Hybrid app directly from within Visual Studio?

I've tried 2 approaches to get this to install:

Method 1:

1. Create a "plugin" directory
2. Download the code from
   https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin and extract into
   the plugin directory
3. Compile/build

This seems to "work" but then bombs out with:

```
Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME
```

Method 2:

1. Open the config.xml file
2. Add in the following "vs:feature" tag:
3. Compile/build

> ```
> <vs:features>
>  <vs:feature>com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect</vs:feature>
> ```
>
> This method also seems to "work", showing a line in the build Output window:

```
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect"
```

But then it too bombs out with the ever annoying:

```
Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME
```

Can someone PLEASE tell me where to add these two variables in so that the thing builds???

I have the values available.

I can't seem to use the CLI to install this plugin into my solution because I get an error like:

```
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Hi @Tom, I still haven't got this to work. No matter what I do I keep getting the error.

Comment: Hi @Tom, After creating a new project and following his steps outlined, I've sent the source code to the email address that Avani suggested in the other answer below.  If/when I hear from them, I'll post anything they find.

Comment: For those following this question, see the link below. Hopefully one of us will get the solution soon.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553724/add-a-plugin-with-variables

Comment: Did you ever get a reply to this? I had to go back to not using VS for an app but i'd really like to put it back in to VS

Comment: I did.  Essentially VS doesn't support it and you have to create a CLI app and use the plugin that way.

Comment: Ah - so you don't use the VS stuff at all now?

Comment: I created the project using the CLI and cordova commands, and use VS for the text editing and UI development.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend going with ***method 1*** since it provides greater flexibility to configure your plugin. That being said, what you are running into is a common [issue](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/issues/21) with the FacebookConnect plugin when it is added manually instead of using the cordova CLI. To add the app ID and app name, do the following as documented [here](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html).

In `plugin.xml`,  find the below lines `<preference name="APP_ID">
<preference name="APP_NAME">` and modify them to `<param name="APP_ID" value="<id of your app>" />
<param name="APP_NAME" value="<name of your app>" />`

This will get you past the error.

However, the plugin is written in Java and the references are not precompiled. So, you will run into issues like `com.facebook.blah` not found. To get past these additional compilation issues, follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/436#issuecomment-47322443), which let you build the plugin dependencies without eclipse.

To use the CLI to install the plugin, you need to run the commands from `<projectRoot>\bld\debug\platform\<yourplatform>` where the cordova projects are created.

Comment: Hi @Avani,  Still no luck. I can't seem to get the APP_ID/APP_NAME values anywhere that the VS2013 compiler needs them.  I did as you suggested.  I found the page you referenced at some point just before you posted your answer.
Have you been able to install this facebookConnect plugin into a VS2013 Multi-deviice Hybrid app project?
If so, could you share your step by step notes on how to do it to compile stage, because I'm really struggling with it.
Thanks

Comment: Sure.
1. Download the plugin source from GIT
2. Create a plugins folder in your project.
3. Copy the downloaded source into the plugins folder.
4. Open plugin.xml within the plugin itself and make the changes to the `preference name='blah'` parameters by changing them to `param name="APP_NAME" value = <blah>`
5. build your project.

This is what worked for me. If you are still blocked on this, would you mind emailing vscordovatools@microsoft.com and we can take it from there?

Comment: Hi @Avani,  I have shot an email off to the email address you listed.  If you are looking out for it, the subject is "Trouble compiling a Multi-device Hybrid App with Facebook Connect plugin".
Any help you guys can give me will be very much appreciated, I've been battling with this for about 3 weeks now.

Comment: You're my new best friend Ads. If you could let me know when / if they reply we'll be friends forever!

Comment: Please make sure you are changing  <preference name="APP_ID" />
    <preference name="APP_NAME" /> elements in plugin.xml to <params  name="APP_ID" value="Facebook-app-id"/>
<params  name="APP_NAME" value="Facebook-app-name"/>, this will get you past Error 103 Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably miss is the renaming of the element from preference to param

in `plugin.xml` change preference to param for app name and app id an also enter their value.

```
<preference name="APP_NAME"> 
to 
<param name="APP_NAME" value="<name of your app>" />
```