# Add a plugin with variables

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

How do you add an plugin not using the `<vs:feature />` sections. I need to add some plugins that when you add them they ask for variables. If i use cordova plugin add, how do I then reference the plugin in the application?

This is driving me crazy, seems a proper over site and makes the whole thing unusable.

I keep getting the error:

```
Error   17  Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME   F:\Development\sdfsdfsd\sdfdsfi\EXEC    1   1   sdfsdfsd
Error   18  The command ""C:\Users\Tom.AD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Release --projectDir . --projectName "sdffds" --language "en-US"" exited with code 8.  C:\Users\Tom.AD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   182 5   sdfdsff
```

I've tried adding the following in the config.xml

```
 <preference name="APP_ID" value="ssssss" />
  <preference name="APP_NAME" value="ssssss" />
```

And

```
<vs:feature>
      https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git
      <preference name="APP_ID" value="sssss" />
      <preference name="APP_NAME" value="ssss" />
    </vs:feature>
```

And

```
<vs:feature>
      https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git
      <params name="APP_ID" value="ssssss" />
      <params name="APP_NAME" value="sssss" />
    </vs:feature
```

Comment: For anyone else following this question, a similar question is at the link below.  Hopefully one of us will get this sorted out quickly.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516444/specifying-app-id-and-app-name-for-facebookconnect-in-a-multi-device-hybrid-app

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for this plugin covers this here:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md

Here is their example:

```
cordova -d plugin add /Users/your/path/here/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Comment: My question is how do I use it in Visual Studios Multi-device-hybrid-apps which adds plugins using <vs:feature>link to git</vs:feature> not using plugin add

Comment: Reading through the documentation for that, there is no mention of variables. I am assuming that means it's not supported (yet). Though I would try `<vs:feature>link to git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"</vs:feature>` if you haven't already

Comment: Adding variables to your plugin via the `config.xml` file is not supported in Visual Studio at this time. The only way to work around it is to copy the contents into a `plugins` folder in your project and modify the `plugin.xml` file as documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25532090/3900092)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN suggest to manually install it and enter the variables yourself

1. download as zip from github
2. extract to your /plugiuns folder (create if it doesnt exist)
3. in your unpacked plugin edit plugin.xml:

   delete `<preference name="APP_ID"> and  <preference name="APP_NAME">`

   add `<params name="APP_ID" value="ssssss" />`
        `<params name="APP_NAME" value="sssss" />`

Answer (score 0):

For VS2015RC try like this

```
 <vs:plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" source="npm" version="3.11.0">
   <param name="BILLING_KEY" value="CONSTRUCT_YOUR"/>
</vs:plugin>
```

OR

```
<vs:plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" version="3.11.0" />
```

modify plugins\fetch.json like this

```
{
"cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {
      "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git",
        "subdir": "."
      },
       "variables": {
            "BILLING_KEY": "CONSTRUCT_YOUR"
        } 
    }
```